# querySelectorAll selects all similar classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Calendar is using 3 different classes to style its child elements: "old day", "day", "new day". Trying to querySelectorAll element with class name "day" also captures the other two classes, so when i say something like:

```
t = document.getElementByTagName('table');
d = t.item(0).querySelectorAll('.day');
/* also selects td.new.day and td.old.day */

for (i = 0; i < d.length: i ++) {
     if(d[i].textContent == 28) {
         d[i].click();
     }
}
```

I will get click on old 28th instead of current month 28th.

How do i select "day" class of td element without also selecting "old day" and "new day"?

Comment: "old day" and "new day" are both combinations of two classes. You might want to filter away elements with either of the classes old and new in your loop (not to mention your comparison operator is wrong).

Comment: `td.day:not(.old):not(.new)`

Comment: alright filter away might be an option, but is there any better way? I might not know how to do this in less then 30 minutes..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:not` to specify which classes you don't want to match.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".red:not(.big):not(.small)").forEach(e => {
  e.style.marginLeft = "100px";
});
```

```css
.red {color: red;}
.big {font-size: 20px}
.small {font-size: 12px}
```

```html
<a class="red">red</a><br>
<a class="red big">red big</a><br>
<a class="red small">red small</a>
```